# Reference to Self in Static Initializer

Tags: java, class, exception, static, null

I have a problem with three classes in a java program, I'm using `public static final` references of the same class type in a static initializer, but these classes also have `public static final` references of themselves, and eventually point back to the uninitialized class (leading to a null). I'm using a strategy that uses the static references as constants, but this odd chaining behavior keeps happening, what alternatives are there if this problem can't be fixed, and can the problem be fixed at all?

Code:

```
public class Foo{
    public static final Foo UNKNOWN_FOO = new Foo(Bar.UNKNOWN_BAR);
    private final Bar bar;
    public Foo(Bar bar){
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

public class Bar{
    public static final Bar UNKNOWN_BAR = new Bar(Baz.UNKNOWN_BAZ);
    private final Baz baz;
    public Bar(Baz baz){
        this.baz = baz;
    }
}

public class Baz{
    public static final Baz UNKNOWN_BAZ = new Baz(Foo.UNKNOWN_FOO);
    private final Foo foo;
    public Baz(Foo foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bad design. Find a way to avoid this circular dependency.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I'm assuming that's was a typo.

Comment: Can you describe (apart from how Java does it) one order of initialization that would make this do what you want it to do? Since there is a cycle in your code, I don't think that there is such an order.

Comment: You could make them not final and initialize them from a single class

Comment: Why do you need this?  What do you actually want your program to do?  Perhaps there's another solution.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm using the static references as constants like for an unknown instance, I suppose as a way to avoid nulls, and also to tell the user that the requested information wasn't found.

Comment: Perhaps you could give each class a second constructor - a private one - that the initialisers could call.  That way, each class might not have to load the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eran mentions, try to avoid circular dependencies. The following web page from google guice's best practices describes how to avoid circular dependencies and resolve them:
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CyclicDependencies

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to construct a network of instances with `final` fields like that ... without using some nasty reflection to modify the `final` values.

Consider this:

```
public class Foo{
    public static final Foo UNKNOWN_FOO = new Foo(Foo.UNKNOWN_FOO);
    private final Foo foo;
    public Foo(Foo foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Even this won't work.  The `foo` field of `Foo.UNKNOWN_FOO` will be `null`.

To make this work, either the `foo` field or the `UNKNOWN_FOO` field must be non-final.  For example:

```
public class Foo{
    public static final Foo UNKNOWN_FOO;
    static {
        Foo tmp = new Foo(null);
        tmp.foo = tmp;
        UNKNOWN_FOO = tmp;
    }
    private Foo foo;  // NOT final!!
    public Foo(Foo foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

In this case, we can probably get away with `foo` being non-final because it is `private` and there are no setters.

In your more complicated case, you will need to expose a setter method so that something can "close the loop" for the static final objects ... once they have all been created.  But you could arrange that the setter can only be called once; e.g.

```
   public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
       if (this.foo != null) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("Already set");
       }
       this.foo = foo;
   }
```

---

But I concur with the other comments and answers.  These circular dependencies have "bad design" smell ... to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work, but I haven't tested it (**EDIT:** I've tested it, and it works):

```
public class Foo{
    private static Foo tempUnknownFoo = null;
    public static final Foo UNKNOWN_FOO = createUnknownFoo();
    static Foo createUnknownFoo() {
        if (tempUnknownFoo == null) {
            tempUnknownFoo = new Foo();
            tempUnknownFoo.bar = Bar.createUnknownBar();
        }
        return tempUnknownFoo;
    }        
    private Foo() { }

    private Bar bar;
    public Foo(Bar bar){
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

and similarly for `Bar` and `Baz` classes.

When the first class is loaded, one of the `create` methods is called.  This will set the temp variable and call the second `create` method, which will set another temp variable and call the third `create` method, which will set another temp variable and call the first method recursively.  But since the temp variable in that class has already been set, the method simply returns it, and there is no more recursion.

Some things to note: I needed to add a new `tempUnknownFoo` that isn't `final`; otherwise it couldn't be set in the `createUnknownFoo` method.  The `createUnknownFoo` method is package-private.  I'm assuming that all three classes will be in the same package, thus they should all be able to call the other classes' `createUnknown` methods, but other classes not in that package won't be able to.  I added a private no-argument constructor that would be used only by `createUnknown`.  I had to remove the `final` from `bar`, but since it's `private` it shouldn't be a problem.

P.S. Please don't take the comments about circular dependencies too rigidly.  *Often*, circular dependencies are a sign of a defective design; the structure of classes in an application usually end up having some kind of hierarchy or "layer" structure to them, and in such cases, a circular dependency usually means someone added a new feature in a hacky way without thinking about how it fits into the overall structure.  But in a compiler, for instance, you're going to have all kinds of entities referring to each other all over the place, and there will be circular dependencies.  There are other legitimate uses of circular dependencies.  There are definitely plenty of illegitimate uses, but I don't think it's right to attack any circular dependency one sees, without recognizing that there are legitimate reasons to use them.  Yours may well be a legitimate use, but I can't tell.  Too many "rules of thumb" get turned into dogma too much of the time.

Comment: When you are creating Foo using the statement: "tempUnknownFoo = new Foo();", the Foo object is created without a dependency to Bar?

Comment: @niran Yes.  I added a private no-arg constructor just for that purpose.  The `bar` field is set later.

Comment: ah ok...but in the case of multi-threaded code, where the objects Foo, Bar and Baz are created at possibly the same time, would the static method "createUnknownFoo()" and others like it in Bar and Baz have to be synchronized? So, "static Foo createUnknownFoo()" becomes "synchronized static Foo createUnknownFoo()" ? If so, you might get a possible deadlock while one is waiting for the other?

Comment: @niran I was assuming the classes would all be loaded at the beginning of the program and there wouldn't be any multithreading issues.  If that's not the case, I think having all three `createUnknown***` methods synchronize on some common object will work.